# Using Linux API headers made for C in C++

Tags: c++, c, linux

Let's consider this piece of code:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main(void) {

    char hi[14] = "Hello world!\n";

    if (write(1, hi, strlen(hi)) < 0) {
        perror("write");
    }

    cout << "Done" << endl;

    return 0;

}
```

Here, I'm mixing all kinds of C and C++ code to make something ... **work**. I'm writing on `stdout` directly and using some C headers like `string.h` and `stdio.h`. Is this considered bad? Could undefined behavior arise? Is C code "compatible" with C++ so I just include it and use it?

The program works just fine.

```
Hello world!
Done
```

Comment: "using namespace std;" is considered to be worse offense than using C headers and library functions.

Comment: This is a so called `C-style C++ program`. You can include `cstring` instead of `string.h`, but also without this change it is a valid C++ program. Some programmers think it is bad style to write a C++ program which looks like a C program.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik It was just a thing to "demo" that it is C++. lol

So there is no compatibility issues with GCC if I write C code in C++?

Comment: No. The headers just need to wrap everything inside `extern "C"`, which the standard headers already do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is this considered bad?

Some programmers consider it bad style to use C library functions when there are superior C++ library functions available. However, there are cases where it is better to use the C library functions.

> Could undefined behavior arise?

Probably not. The C++ standard library incorporates almost the entire C standard library (with a few minor changes), so calls to C library functions from C++ are well-defined. As for functions such as `write`, their behaviour is defined by POSIX.

> Is C code "compatible" with C++ so I just include it and use it?

For standard C library headers, yes. For implementation headers, typically yes; they are usually designed so that they can be validly included into C++ programs. For other headers... maybe. Not all C code is valid C++, but the degree of compatibility is high.

Answer (score 0):

C++ forked from C a long time so, and the two languages have evolved independently.

The C++ standard describes deliberate incompatibilities that were introduced to C++ relative to the C standard from which it derived: http://eel.is/c++draft/diff.iso.

The mistake people make is in thinking this is a complete list of differences. C itself has evolved, and while parts of C99 were incorporated in recent versions of C++ not all have (VLAs, flexible array members,  compound literals, ...).

C11 made the gap much wider, from small things like the removal of gets (still included in C++17) to things like bounds checking interfaces, threading support, and c-variants of c++ features like _the Static_assert keyword.

So for the most part you can get away with old-C-ish code in a C++ program, a few small changes that will cause compiler errors, a couple that might not, and nearly 20 years of C advances that you only have partial accesso to.

If you really want to write C-like code, consider *writing C code* and taking advantage of the full set of language improvements available in that language. The result will be much higher quality code than the rubbish you'll knock up restricting yourself to C++'s subset of C.

Answer (score -1):

Gala,

Yes this is fine.  C++ is a superset of C, you can blend the two with ease.  In fact, many older programmers (like me) write C++ with a C style.  In this style, printf, strcpy, no templates, RogueWave rather than stl, etc are used with C++ classes.   Sometimes this is termed 'C with classes'.

--Matt

Comment: Unless you are using something older than c++98, c++ is not a superset of C.

Comment: His comment was about -generally- using C headers and common functions in C++.  In this sense, a C++ compiler is a superset of C.  The languages have diverged but vanilla C will be fine.    As the OP noted, his example program works just fine.